# How to set input and button horizontally with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I need to set input with button horizontally like this and it works with this code

[image]

```js
< label
for = "rootFolder"
class = "flex mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300" >
  Processing Directory <
  /label> <
  div class = "mb-6 flex" >
  <
  input type = "rootFolder"
id = "rootFolder"
class = "bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
placeholder = ""
required / >
  <
  button class = "text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" >
  add <
  /button> <
  /div>
```

But I need to change add text to Korean, So I just change it but it makes it like this.

Not only does the text look vertical, but it also changes the size of the Input tag. What is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem with the `width` you gave to the `input`. I removed it and used `grow` instead and also removed the width of the `button`. See the link below:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/kRknIVE2Ra